# Stop Firefox requesting JavaScript files squentially

Tags: firefox, script, java, javascript, firebug

I am using Firefox 3.6.12, when I inspect the site I am working on with Firebug, all the Java script files are requested/loaded in sequence, meaning the page takes a long time to load.

When my colleague does the same thing with the same browser, the JavaScript files are requested in parallel. Is there a setting for this?

Comment: Is it a Firebug thing? Does the site load slowly when Firebug is disabled? What about for your friend?

Comment: I understood that sequential loading of JS files was normal; does your colleague have any plugins no their profile that may have modified this? Have you taken file caching in to account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit 'about:config', filter by 'network.http.pipelining' and set the entry to 'true'.

If the entry doesn't exist you can create a new Boolean entry that's set to 'true'

See [the Knowledge Base](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) if you're not familiar with this interface.

**Note** that doing that can cause websites to react erratically. Many web developers assume (quite reasonably) that JS scripts will run sequentially. This will likely break stuff!